# ios persistent storage framework

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm looking to save a bunch of 'recently accessed' information in my iOS app. For example, if a user views 5 articles, those 5 articles will persistently appear in a recently viewed section.

I was looking into core data and property lists but it all seems pretty complex for such a simple feature. Is there some sort of framework (like Lockbox for keychain) to help make persistent storage a bit easier?

Comment: maybe `NSUserdefault` that would do if it is not a lot of data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way has to be to use the `NSUserDefaults` class. This class stores app-specific preferences to a property list, but all file handling is encapsulated by the class.

To get the object:

```
NSUserDefaults* settings = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
```

To read a setting:

```
NSArray* mru = [settings valueForKey:@"MostRecentlyUsed"];
NSLog(@"Setting: %@", mru);
```

To write a setting:

```
[settings setValue:@[@"A", @"B", @"C", @"D", @"E", @"F"] forKey:@"MostRecentlyUsed"];
[settings synchronize];
```

(The synchronize method writes the changes to the file, it is useful to do this once you have set all your settings to avoid losing them if the app terminates unexpectedly)

Answer (score 0):

For very simple storage of single objects, look at [NSUserDefaults](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

For basic storage of non-basic objects, look at [NSFileManager](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsfilemanager_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for accessing your App's document directory and [NSCoder](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSCoder_Class/Reference/NSCoder.html) for serialization data.